# producing an artifact of a Spring Boot application that can be used as a dependency

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jar

My goal is to produce an artifact of my Spring Boot application that I can use as a **dependency** and [edit] that is a **fat jar**, that is, it contains all the dependencies of my application [edit].

I use **gradle** as a build tool with the following plugins:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.14.RELEASE'
    id 'org.jetbrains.gradle.plugin.idea-ext' version '1.1.6'
}
```

Now, the Spring Boot documentation states at
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.build.use-a-spring-boot-application-as-dependency that

'Spring Boot’s Maven and **Gradle plugins** must be configured to produce a separate artifact that is suitable for use as a dependency [...] To produce the two artifacts, one that can be used as a dependency and one that is executable, a classifier must be specified. This classifier is applied to the name of the executable archive, leaving the default archive for use as a dependency.'

This is followed by a description on how to do this with the build tool maven, but there is no mentioning of how to do this in gradle.

Any help of how to set this up with gradle is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building with Gradle, an artifact with a `plain` classifier [is built by default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable.and-plain-archives). This artifact is a standard, plain jar file that is suitable for use as a dependency.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Andy! I forgot one major point in my original questions and just edited it: my goal is to produce an artifact that is an uber/fat jar.

Comment: You cannot use a Spring Boot fat jar as a dependency. A Spring Boot fat jar places its classes in `BOOT-INF/classes` and all of the dependencies in `BOOT-INF/lib`. When used as a normal dependency, these classes and jar files won't be found as a standard `ClassLoader` doesn't know where to look for them.